# Looking for latest Blake2 b2sum.exe for Windows

Tags: windows, hashing, checksum

I downloaded the b2sum file from blake2.net but it's from 2013 and doesn't seem to support the "compare" `-c` option. Several online references show several options which I cannot access with the version I have. It says `b2sum: uknown option -- c`

Anyone know where to find the latest version?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest version of [*bare* `b2sum`](https://github.com/BLAKE2/BLAKE2/tree/master/b2sum) does not support `-c` either.

What happens is GNU Coreutils in Linux uses code from `md5sum.c` (along with `b2sum.c`) to build `b2sum` binary. The code in `md5sum.c` is deliberately written to enhance utilities with md5sum-like interface and to provide common options for them, including `-c`.

One can confirm this e.g. in Ubuntu by running `apt-get source coreutils`, entering the resulting directory, then examining `src/blake2/b2sum.c`, `src/md5sum.c` and (after running `./configure`) the `Makefile`. Or check the sources [here](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/tree/master/src).

In effect `b2sum` from GNU Coreutils supports `-c` (and few other options not covered in `b2sum.c`). The [manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/b2sum.1.html) and "online references" you mentioned describe the option, users use it.

---

To get `b2sum` that supports `-c` in Windows, you need to replicate the mechanism. Git for Windows did this for you. Proceed like this:

1. Download a portable version that fits your OS: [Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win).
2. Unpack.
3. Find `b2sum.exe` in `usr\bin`. This executable supports `-c`.

You can use `b2sum.exe` without the rest of Git but the executable needs few dlls. In my tests these were `msys-2.0.dll`, `msys-iconv-2.dll` and `msys-intl-8.dll`, all from `usr\bin`. If you decide you don't need Git and want to keep `b2sum.exe` only, then keep these dlls as well.

Answer (score 2):

I also needed it so I ended up compiling it from CoreUtils source. Latest b2sum can be found [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/b2sum-for-windows/).

Comment: The 2013 version offers BLAKE2sp and other variations. In a sample run, that BLAKE2sp option gave me the same hash as 7-zip. I did not find a BLAKE2sp option in Albanese's version. Albanese's version also set off my Norton antivirus. Hopefully that was a false positive.